# Standardize xtab matrices of differing dimensions into the same dimension

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of xtabs tables of differing row length but the same column lenth. The row names are combinations of two letter grades e.g. "A-B", and the column names are a single letter grade e.g. "A".  I would like to make all the matrices the same dimension and then add them.

Since the matrices in the list are of differing dimensions I know I have to transform them first into the same dimensions before I can I add them. I created a matrix that has all the possible combinations of letter grades (36 x 6). How do make all the matrices in the list have the same dimensions as the 36 x 6 matrix and ensure the order is adhered?

```
row.order <- c( "Aa", "A",   "Baa", "Ba",  "B", "Caa")

# all possible combinations 
all.crossings <- expand.grid(row.order, row.order, row.order)

all.crossings <-
all.crossings %>% 
mutate(ij = paste(Var1, Var2, sep = "-"),
     k = Var2,
     Count = 0) %>%
select(ij, k, Count)

# use xtabs to transfor into matrix form
all.crossings <- xtabs(Count~ij+k, data = all.crossings)
attributes(all.crossings)$class <- "matrix"
```

This is how my list of xtab matrices look like:

```
> data_out.2nd.ord
[[1]]
           k
ij        Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-Ba     0  0   0  1  1   0
  A-Baa    0  0   2  1  2   0
  Aa-A     1  2   0  0  0   0
  Aa-Ba    0  0   0  1  0   0
  Aa-Baa   0  2   0  1  1   0
  B-A      0  0   0  1  0   0
  B-B      0  0   1  3 14   5
  B-Ba     0  0   1  1  3   3
  B-Baa    0  0   2  0  0   1
  B-Caa    0  0   1  3  5   7
  Ba-A     0  0   0  2  0   0
  Ba-B     0  0   2  5  3   2
  Ba-Ba    0  0   1  2  5   0
  Ba-Baa   0  1   0  1  1   1
  Ba-Caa   0  0   1  1  2   3
  Baa-A    0  0   0  2  0   0
  Baa-Aa   0  1   0  0  0   0
  Baa-B    0  0   0  2  1   2
  Baa-Ba   0  0   3  2  1   0
  Baa-Baa  1  0   3  2  1   0
  Baa-Caa  0  0   1  0  1   0
  Caa-B    0  0   0  0  6   6
  Caa-Ba   0  0   0  0  1   0
  Caa-Baa  0  0   1  0  0   0
  Caa-Caa  0  0   0  2  5  12

[[2]]
     k
ij        Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-A      0  0   2  0  0   0
  A-Aa     0  1   0  0  0   0
  A-Ba     0  0   1  3  1   0
  Aa-A     0  1   0  0  0   0
  B-B      0  0   2  3 13   6
  B-Ba     0  0   2  4  3   1
  B-Baa    0  0   2  0  1   0
  B-Caa    0  0   1  1  8   5
  Ba-B     0  1   0  6  2   2
  Ba-Ba    1  2   2  1  1   0
  Ba-Baa   0  0   1  1  2   1
  Ba-Caa   0  0   0  2  0   1
  Baa-A    0  1   2  0  0   0
  Baa-Aa   0  1   0  0  0   0
  Baa-B    0  0   1  3  1   0
  Baa-Ba   0  1   2  1  1   0
  Baa-Baa  0  2   0  5  0   1
  Baa-Caa  0  0   0  1  1   0
  Caa-B    0  0   0  2  6   5
  Caa-Ba   0  0   1  2  0   3
  Caa-Baa  1  1   0  1  0   0
  Caa-Caa  0  0   0  1  7  14

[[3]]
     k
ij        Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-A      0  0   0  1  1   0
  A-Baa    0  1   1  1  1   0
  Aa-A     0  2   0  0  0   0
  B-A      0  1   0  0  0   0
  B-B      0  0   2  3 14   3
  B-Ba     0  1   1  5  4   3
  B-Baa    0  0   2  0  1   0
  B-Caa    0  1   1  2  3   6
  Ba-A     0  0   2  0  1   0
  Ba-Aa    0  0   1  0  0   0
  Ba-B     0  0   0  2  2   2
  Ba-Ba    0  0   4  4  3   0
  Ba-Baa   0  0   2  2  2   2
  Ba-Caa   0  0   0  0  1   3
  Baa-A    0  0   3  0  0   0
  Baa-Aa   0  0   0  0  1   0
  Baa-B    0  0   0  2  0   1
  Baa-Ba   0  0   2  3  2   0
  Baa-Baa  0  0   2  0  1   0
  Baa-Caa  0  0   0  2  0   0
  Caa-B    0  0   0  0  9   7
  Caa-Ba   0  0   0  1  1   3
  Caa-Baa  0  0   0  1  0   0
  Caa-Caa  0  0   0  1  7  12
```

all the matrices in dput(head(lapply(data_out.2nd.ord, as.matrix),3)):

```
list(structure(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 14L, 
3L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 12L), .Dim = c(25L, 6L
), .Dimnames = list(ij = c("A-Ba", "A-Baa", "Aa-A", "Aa-Ba", 
"Aa-Baa", "B-A", "B-B", "B-Ba", "B-Baa", "B-Caa", "Ba-A", "Ba-B", 
"Ba-Ba", "Ba-Baa", "Ba-Caa", "Baa-A", "Baa-Aa", "Baa-B", "Baa-Ba", 
"Baa-Baa", "Baa-Caa", "Caa-B", "Caa-Ba", "Caa-Baa", "Caa-Caa"
), k = c("Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ ij + k, data = .)), structure(c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 13L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
5L, 3L, 0L, 14L), .Dim = c(22L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(ij = c("A-A", 
"A-Aa", "A-Ba", "Aa-A", "B-B", "B-Ba", "B-Baa", "B-Caa", "Ba-B", 
"Ba-Ba", "Ba-Baa", "Ba-Caa", "Baa-A", "Baa-Aa", "Baa-B", "Baa-Ba", 
"Baa-Baa", "Baa-Caa", "Caa-B", "Caa-Ba", "Caa-Baa", "Caa-Caa"
), k = c("Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ ij + k, data = .)), structure(c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 
0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 3L, 0L, 12L
), .Dim = c(24L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(ij = c("A-A", "A-Baa", 
"Aa-A", "B-A", "B-B", "B-Ba", "B-Baa", "B-Caa", "Ba-A", "Ba-Aa", 
"Ba-B", "Ba-Ba", "Ba-Baa", "Ba-Caa", "Baa-A", "Baa-Aa", "Baa-B", 
"Baa-Ba", "Baa-Baa", "Baa-Caa", "Caa-B", "Caa-Ba", "Caa-Baa", 
"Caa-Caa"), k = c("Aa", "A", "Baa", "Ba", "B", "Caa")), class = c("xtabs", 
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = n ~ ij + k, data = .)))
```

Comment: Did you make that with tidyverse? There is something in there  that causes an error (`Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : object '.' not found`) when you try to assign that structure to a name .

Comment: Yes I used tidyverse.

Comment: How about replacing that output with output from  `dput( head( lapply( data_out.2nd.ord, as.matrix), 3)` so the R interpreter does try to find the original data source? And we don't get output that has 15 tables.

Comment: @42- I've updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to paste the dput output from the question into R it gives an error so we used the input shown in the Note at the end.

Here are two different approaches.

**1) zoo** Set `nms` to the union of the rownames and then convert each matrix to zoo using its rownames as the index and merging each such zoo object with a zero width zoo object having an index of `nms`.  At this point each zoo object has the same row and column names.  Finally sum them using `Reduce`.

```
library(zoo)

nms <- Reduce(union, lapply(L, rownames))
Lz <- lapply(L, function(x) merge(zoo(x, rownames(x)), zoo(, nms), fill = 0))
m <- as.matrix(Reduce(`+`, Lz))
head(m)
##       Aa A Baa Ba B Caa
## A-A    0 0   2  1 1   0
## A-Aa   0 1   0  0 0   0
## A-Ba   0 0   1  4 2   0
## A-Baa  0 1   3  2 3   0
## Aa-A   1 5   0  0 0   0
## Aa-Ba  0 0   0  1 0   0
```

**2) as.data.frame**  Use `as.data.frame` to convert each component of the list `L` to long form, `aggregate` the resulting data frames and then use `xtabs` to convert back to wide form.

```
dd <- do.call("rbind", lapply(L, as.data.frame))
ag <- aggregate(Freq ~., dd, sum)
names(ag) <- c("ij", "k", "Freq")
xt <- xtabs(Freq ~., ag)
head(xt)
##         k
## ij       Aa A Baa Ba B Caa
##   A-Ba    0 0   1  4 2   0
##   A-Baa   0 1   3  2 3   0
##   Aa-A    1 5   0  0 0   0
##   Aa-Ba   0 0   0  1 0   0
##   Aa-Baa  0 2   0  1 1   0
##   B-A     0 1   0  1 0   0
```

### Note

```
Lines1 <- " Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-Ba     0  0   0  1  1   0
  A-Baa    0  0   2  1  2   0
  Aa-A     1  2   0  0  0   0
  Aa-Ba    0  0   0  1  0   0
  Aa-Baa   0  2   0  1  1   0
  B-A      0  0   0  1  0   0
  B-B      0  0   1  3 14   5
  B-Ba     0  0   1  1  3   3
  B-Baa    0  0   2  0  0   1
  B-Caa    0  0   1  3  5   7
  Ba-A     0  0   0  2  0   0
  Ba-B     0  0   2  5  3   2
  Ba-Ba    0  0   1  2  5   0
  Ba-Baa   0  1   0  1  1   1
  Ba-Caa   0  0   1  1  2   3
  Baa-A    0  0   0  2  0   0
  Baa-Aa   0  1   0  0  0   0
  Baa-B    0  0   0  2  1   2
  Baa-Ba   0  0   3  2  1   0
  Baa-Baa  1  0   3  2  1   0
  Baa-Caa  0  0   1  0  1   0
  Caa-B    0  0   0  0  6   6
  Caa-Ba   0  0   0  0  1   0
  Caa-Baa  0  0   1  0  0   0
  Caa-Caa  0  0   0  2  5  12"

Lines2 <- "Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-A      0  0   2  0  0   0
  A-Aa     0  1   0  0  0   0
  A-Ba     0  0   1  3  1   0
  Aa-A     0  1   0  0  0   0
  B-B      0  0   2  3 13   6
  B-Ba     0  0   2  4  3   1
  B-Baa    0  0   2  0  1   0
  B-Caa    0  0   1  1  8   5
  Ba-B     0  1   0  6  2   2
  Ba-Ba    1  2   2  1  1   0
  Ba-Baa   0  0   1  1  2   1
  Ba-Caa   0  0   0  2  0   1
  Baa-A    0  1   2  0  0   0
  Baa-Aa   0  1   0  0  0   0
  Baa-B    0  0   1  3  1   0
  Baa-Ba   0  1   2  1  1   0
  Baa-Baa  0  2   0  5  0   1
  Baa-Caa  0  0   0  1  1   0
  Caa-B    0  0   0  2  6   5
  Caa-Ba   0  0   1  2  0   3
  Caa-Baa  1  1   0  1  0   0
  Caa-Caa  0  0   0  1  7  14"

Lines3 <- "Aa  A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-A      0  0   0  1  1   0
  A-Baa    0  1   1  1  1   0
  Aa-A     0  2   0  0  0   0
  B-A      0  1   0  0  0   0
  B-B      0  0   2  3 14   3
  B-Ba     0  1   1  5  4   3
  B-Baa    0  0   2  0  1   0
  B-Caa    0  1   1  2  3   6
  Ba-A     0  0   2  0  1   0
  Ba-Aa    0  0   1  0  0   0
  Ba-B     0  0   0  2  2   2
  Ba-Ba    0  0   4  4  3   0
  Ba-Baa   0  0   2  2  2   2
  Ba-Caa   0  0   0  0  1   3
  Baa-A    0  0   3  0  0   0
  Baa-Aa   0  0   0  0  1   0
  Baa-B    0  0   0  2  0   1
  Baa-Ba   0  0   2  3  2   0
  Baa-Baa  0  0   2  0  1   0
  Baa-Caa  0  0   0  2  0   0
  Caa-B    0  0   0  0  9   7
  Caa-Ba   0  0   0  1  1   3
  Caa-Baa  0  0   0  1  0   0
  Caa-Caa  0  0   0  1  7  12"

t1 <- as.table(as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines1, strip.white = TRUE)))
t2 <- as.table(as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines2, strip.white = TRUE)))
t3 <- as.table(as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines3, strip.white = TRUE)))

L <- list(t1, t2, t3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that has R code for this pseudo code for it's body and returns a modified all.crossings:

```
for each rowname in data-matrix{
     add this row from datamatrix to matching row in all.crossings
                                }
```

Actual code:

```
addmat <- function(X, res){ for( r in rownames(X)) { res[r, ] <- X[r,]+res[r,] }; res}
```

That should be fairly easy because pulling a row can use character indexing and then assignment can as well.

Then do a for-loop over the items in `data_out.2nd.ord` to run this function three times.

```
 res <- all.crossings; for( s in seq_along(dat) ){  
                                    res <- addmat( dat[[s]], res=res) }
```

Result on data offered:

```
> res
         k
ij        Aa A Baa Ba  B Caa
  A-A      0 0   2  1  1   0
  A-Aa     0 1   0  0  0   0
  A-B      0 0   0  0  0   0
  A-Ba     0 0   1  4  2   0
  A-Baa    0 1   3  2  3   0
  A-Caa    0 0   0  0  0   0
  Aa-A     1 5   0  0  0   0
  Aa-Aa    0 0   0  0  0   0
  Aa-B     0 0   0  0  0   0
  Aa-Ba    0 0   0  1  0   0
  Aa-Baa   0 2   0  1  1   0
  Aa-Caa   0 0   0  0  0   0
  B-A      0 1   0  1  0   0
  B-Aa     0 0   0  0  0   0
  B-B      0 0   5  9 41  14
  B-Ba     0 1   4 10 10   7
  B-Baa    0 0   6  0  2   1
  B-Caa    0 1   3  6 16  18
  Ba-A     0 0   2  2  1   0
  Ba-Aa    0 0   1  0  0   0
  Ba-B     0 1   2 13  7   6
  Ba-Ba    1 2   7  7  9   0
  Ba-Baa   0 1   3  4  5   4
  Ba-Caa   0 0   1  3  3   7
  Baa-A    0 1   5  2  0   0
  Baa-Aa   0 2   0  0  1   0
  Baa-B    0 0   1  7  2   3
  Baa-Ba   0 1   7  6  4   0
  Baa-Baa  1 2   5  7  2   1
  Baa-Caa  0 0   1  3  2   0
  Caa-A    0 0   0  0  0   0
  Caa-Aa   0 0   0  0  0   0
  Caa-B    0 0   0  2 21  18
  Caa-Ba   0 0   1  3  2   6
  Caa-Baa  1 1   1  2  0   0
  Caa-Caa  0 0   0  4 19  38
attr(,"class")
[1] "matrix"
attr(,"call")
xtabs(formula = Count ~ ij + k, data = all.crossings)
```

Comment: I've added the output

Comment: Looking at my code I'm wondering if the function addmat could be made more efficient? Perhaps just:  `function( inp, res){ res[ rownames(inp) ] <- inp; res}` , and would be vectorized and probably more efficient.